# How do I fix loss: nan for Keras in Python?

Tags: python, keras, nan, loss

I'm trying to perform a regression using Keras in Python. During training, the loss, mean_squared_error, val_mean_squared_error are all nan. How can I fix this?

I've checked thoroughly, and there are no missing values (NaNs) or infinite values in my data. I've also tried gradient value clipping and gradient norm scaling, but none of them worked.

Below is my neural net model.

```
model = Sequential()

n_cols = train_X.shape[1]

early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=10)

model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=500, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])
```